# How to focus on a textbox without losing its value

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to manipulate a `TextBox` so that you can click on it or tab on it, and you have focus to change the value without having to backspace to erase the existing value.  The following code works, but if a user doesn't want to change the value and just happens to be tabbing through the controls, the value is lost.  Is there an easy way to do this without having to keep track of current and previous variable values?

Here is the code that gives the user focus, but wipes out the existing value:

```
private void txt_foo_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.Text = string.Empty;
    tb.GotFocus -= txt_panelWidth_GotFocus;
}
```

Comment: Uhm... just select the whole text on focus instead of erasing it? Selected text will be replaced on the first input but stay unchanged when tabbing out without change.

Comment: Maybe try `tb.SelectAll()` instead of setting the text to empty? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectall(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This works when you click inside of a textbox for you?  It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should select the text in the `TextBox` when you tab into it and when you click in it:

```
private void txt_foo_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    tb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tb.SelectAll()));
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly for both tabbing and clicking.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

My solution: select the text

```
void SelectingTextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null && e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
    {
        tb.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Note this `e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab)` condition is something I use with my project in order to only select all text when navigating by tab. You can remove the condition if you always want to select all text. But it can be quite annoying for a user that works with the mouse when all text is selected.

Comment: It selects all text when I tab through it, but not when I click on it.

Comment: @nikotromus yes, exactly as I wrote below the code snippet. You are free to change the condition to meet your requirements, but be sure to avoid any user contact once you shipped it with select on click.

Comment: I took out the if condition all together and it still doesn't select all the text when I click on the textbox.

Comment: I'm curious why you feel like this is a bad thing to do from a user experience perspective?  I could see that for text fields, but for numeric configurations that the user wants to change, why would they want to select a text box, backspace through all the text and then enter in a new value?

Comment: @nikotromus If they like to select everything by mouse, they can just double-click to select all. However, I don't know your detailed use case, but I know how I feel when I enter anything non-trivial and then need to correct a character/number at position 3. If I can't click on position 3 right away and start correcting, I will be annoyed.